# How to handle status bar tap scroll on iOS with Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, scroll, statusbar

Knowing that using just a `Scaffold` as top of our widget tree will give us a `PrimaryScrollController` which results in a tap on status bar on iOS to automatically scroll to top, how you achieve it with a custom `ScrollController`?

If you have multiple scroll controllers and you want to delegate them with such feature, how do you do it? Seems like I’m only able to achieve it with `PrimaryScrollController` which is very limited when you need to handle more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Given that [Flutter itself uses the `PrimaryScrollController` to scroll to top](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/affba75f2efc10c43dfaf19e41863e45673806f3/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/page_scaffold.dart#LL91C3-L102C4) when tapping the status bar on iOS, it seems like a decent way to do this.

You may be able to write a similar function to `animateTo` the top, but instead of using `PrimaryScrollController`, pass in your own `ScrollController` and maybe it will work for your purposes.

I hope that answers your question. If not, could you elaborate on what you meant with it being *limited* and maybe an example of *more stuff*:

> very limited when you need to handle more stuff